# Why ESLint doesn't see all the quotes problems of a JS file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, eslint

**Problem:** ESLint doesn't see all the quotes problems in my JS file where I use React.

**Expected:** See that ESLint checks my errors and show them to me .

**Things that I tried:** I changed some quotes to see the difference and I saw that for the imports ESLint is working, but in the components it doesn't. I checked my rules and there is the 'quotes' rule. I checked my errors to be exactly and just for quotes and I saw that there weren't any problems.

I will attach an image with the problem:

[image]

As you can see, in the first line is everything ok, because I put double quotes. Then in the second and in the third lines there are simple quotes and ESLint can see them. It can be seen that ESLint can see just the quotes problem, nothing more.

And then, then it comes the problem. At the 'flex-container' it can't see that there must be double quotes and it can't fix that. And it's not just an exeption, because on the last line are also single quotes and it can't see that.

My .eslintrc.json file:

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true,
        "node": true,
        "amd": true,
        "jquery": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 12,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "rules": {
        "react/prop-types": "off",
        "react/jsx-uses-react": "warn",
        "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
        "quotes": [
            "error",
            "double",
            {
                "avoidEscape": true
            }
        ]
    },
    "globals": {
        "React": true,
        "ReactDOM": true,
        "ReactRedux": true,
        "ReactRouterDOM": true,
        "Redux": true
    },
    "settings": {
        "react": {
            "version": "detect"
        }
    }
}
```

There I changed some properties for rules, to put 'error' instead of 'off' or 'warn', but it is the same.

What can I do?

Comment: Add `"single":true` in eslintrc and check

Comment: It is the same, the double quotes from imports are being seen as a problem and the 'flex-container' and 'path' that I put for this example also double quotes are being seen without problems.

Comment: It might be because it's a JSX prop value, not a JS string literal (try if it can detect `className={'flex-container'}`). However, I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: You are right, if I put as you said ESLint can see the problem.

Comment: I put an issue on GitHub so I hope it will be resolved one day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the answer from the ESLint authors is:

"The `quotes` rule works as intended in this case, because it checks only string literals.

For JSX attributes you can use the [jsx-quotes](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/jsx-quotes) rule, as in this [demo](https://eslint.org/demo#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)."